# How to close the firefox nightly translation popup with Playwright?

Tags: javascript, playwright, end-to-end

Multiple of my playwright tests are failing on Firefox.

I realized that a popup from Firefox Nightly, proposing to translate the current page from French to English, is preventing my test from clicking the element behind it.

I tried to click on the cancel button of the popup but could not detect the button on the page with the following code:

```
await page.getByText('Cancel').click()
```

and doing:

```
await page.keyboard.press('Escape')
```

do not get rid of the popup even though I does get rid of it when I do it manually with my keyboard.

Using locale, timezone and geo location matching the page language did not get rid of the popup.

Listening for the popup event either as per the ["Handling popups" page](https://playwright.dev/docs/pages#handling-popups) from the playwright documentation.

When I try to use `await page.pause()` the second I press "record" the popup disappears and I can't auto generate the code to close it.

I made [this repository](https://github.com/BenjaminLesne/nightly-popup) with steps to reproduce in the README and it has a video to show the problem.

This is tricky because the "popup" is not from the page but the browser itself. I have no idea how to interact with it with Playwright. (I looked into the doc though)

help

[Here is a screenshot with the popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0mew.png)

Comment: All relevant code should be minimized and in the question itself, not in a GitHub repo. See [mcve] for guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in the current canary version.

Here is how I installed  it:

```bash
yarn add -D playwright@1.40.0-alpha-nov-3-2023 &&
yarn add -D @playwright/test@next
```